# UITextView has long text, the text is not visible, but the textview occupied a large space

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextview

I use `UITextView` in my app. And the `UITextView` has a long text, and this `textview` can not edit and scroll. I display this `UITextView` `auto layout` with Masonry. And when the text is longer than a number, the text become not visible, but still occupied space.

[image: iOS simulator screenshot]

Comment: This problem only happen in simulator, it works well in my iPhone6(iOS 9.2)

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have scroll disabled you will need to update layout yourself on each change in that text view. Otherwise the text will go outside the view frame.

```
// Something like :

// when you got the view loaded:
self.textView.delegate = self

// Update
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
   // Update masonry:
   [textView mas_remakeConstraints^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
       make.height.equalTo(@(textView.intrinsicContentSize.height));
    }];
}
```

Comment: I have add this delegate, but not work. And i found that this delegate method never been called